# Problema ao criar associação many to many utilizando Sequelize (belongsToMany)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize-js

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro ao definir uma associação many to many entre duas tabelas:

```
C:\eadfabet\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\mixin.js:49 throw new Error(`${this.name}.belongsToMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model`);

Error: Teacher.belongsToMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
    at Function.belongsToMany (C:\eadfabet\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\mixin.js:49:13)
    at Function.associate (C:\eadfabet\src\app\models\Teacher.js:33:10)
    at C:\eadfabet\src\database\index.js:26:45
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Database.init (C:\eadfabet\src\database\index.js:25:8)
    at new Database (C:\eadfabet\src\database\index.js:17:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\eadfabet\src\database\index.js:31:20) ...
```

Vou explicar meu cenário, tenho duas tabels, teachers e courses, a associação delas é many to many. 
Para criar a associação, criei uma tabela "pivô" chamada courses_teachers, segue a migration:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('courses_teachers', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      course_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: { model: 'courses', key: 'id' },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      },
      teacher_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: { model: 'teachers', key: 'id' },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      },
      created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
  },

  down: (queryInterface) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('courses_teachers');
  },
};
```

Defini a associação no model courses, não obtive nenhum erro no terminal:

```
import Sequelize, { Model } from 'sequelize';

class Courses extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        name: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      {
        sequelize,
      }
    );
    return this;
  }

  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsToMany(models.Teacher, {
      foreignKey: 'course_id',
      through: 'courses_teachers',
      as: 'teachers',
    });
  }
}

export default Courses;
```

Porém, quando defini a associação no model teachers, obtive o erro relatado acima. 
Model de teachers:

```
import Sequelize, { Model } from 'sequelize';

class Teacher extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        name: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      {
        sequelize,
      }
    );

    return this;
  }

  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsToMany(models.Course, {
      foreignKey: 'teacher_id',
      through: 'courses_teachers',
      as: 'courses',
    });
  }
}

export default Teacher;
```

Estou o dia todo quebrando a cabeça tentando descobrir o que pode estar ocasionando este erro.

Comment: Encontrei o problema, estava me refereindo ao model Course da forma incorreta, o correto é Courses.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei o problema, estava me refereindo ao model Course da forma incorreta, o correto é Courses.

Obrigado @William Prigol Lopes

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490149/problem-creating-many-to-many-association-in-sequelize-belongstomany/61490424#61490424